# Why file isn't reading permission in python with open function of file object? Any one can explain me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, data-science-experience

Why isn't file reading permission in python with the open function of file object? Can anyone explain me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jEmL.png)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you are trying to open a *directory* instead of a *file*.

Change your code so that you `open` a file by its name.